# How to find set of shortest subsequences with minimal collisions from set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm

I've got a list of strings like

- Foobar
- Foobaron
- Foot
- barstool
- barfoo
- footloose

I want to find the set of shortest possible sub-sequences that are unique to each string in the set; the characters in each sub-sequence do not need to be adjacent, just in order as they appear in the original string. For the example above, that would be (along other possibilities)

- `Fb` (as unique to *Foobar* as it gets; collision with *Foobaron* unavoidable)
- `Fn` (unique to *Foobaron*, no other `...F...n...`)
- `Ft` (*Foot*)
- `bs` (*barstool*)
- `bf` (*barfoo*)
- `e` (*footloose*)

Is there an efficient way to mine such sequences and minimize the number of colliding strings (when collisions can't be avoided, e.g. when strings are substrings of other strings) from a given array of strings? More precisely, *chosing the length N, what is the set of sub-sequences of up to N characters each that identify the original strings with the fewest number of collisions.*

Comment: The number of collisions that cannot be avoided is the number of words which are subsequences of other words.

Comment: Why `Fn` for _Foobaron_ and not `on`?

Comment: No reason, `on` would be valid as well and just as good

Comment: The set of strings is given. N is chosen, the largest number of characters the subsequences shall have in the final result. The smaller N is, the larger the number of collisions becomes.

Comment: fixed the typo regarding `N` and `M`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141590/discussion-between-user2722968-and-triptych).

Comment: I've thought of an algorithm that, for each string in turn, examines all distinct *non-dominated* subsequences of that string in increasing length order and finds the shortest that does not appear in any of the other strings. A subsequence X is dominated if some proper subsequence Y of it has the property that, for each other string Z, aligning Y with Z as far left as possible occupies the same rightmost position as aligning X with Z as far left as possible (so, e.g., if there is 1 other string `ABA`, the subsequence `AB` is dominated by `B`).  In practice there can ...

Comment: ... be vastly fewer distinct non-dominated subsequences than distinct subsequences (and vastly fewer *distinct* subsequences than subsequences), though probably not asymptotically fewer.  I don't have time right now to explain in full, but briefly, it uses a BFS through a graph in which each vertex corresponds to a tuple of positions, 1 per string (*including* the "target" string) and there is a directed edge u->v whenever there is a letter c such that for each string s[i], either the first occurrence within s_i of c after u[i] is at v[i], or c does not appear in s_i after u[i].

Comment: Why do you call them subsequence when they are not really sequential? `Fn` is not a subsequence of `Foobaron` but just two of its letters. `Fo` is a subsequence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

Comment: okay - just me!

Comment: `Why` *Fn* `for Foobaron and not on` [Triptych] `No reason,` *on* `would be valid as well and just as good` [user2722968] - just as bad: try *n* - step 0: find characters unique to a string (or does `shortest` refer to *minimum* **longest** *subsequence necessary*? .

Answer (score 4):

I would'nt really call that 'efficient', but you can do better than totally dumb like that:

```
words = ['Foobar', 'Foobaron', 'Foot', 'barstool', 'barfoo', 'footloose']
N = 2
n = len(words)
L = max([len(word) for word in words])

def generate_substrings(word, max_length=None):
    if max_length is None:
        max_length = len(word)
    set_substrings = set()
    set_substrings.add('')
    for charac in word:
        new_substr_list = []
        for substr in set_substrings:
            new_substr = substr + charac
            if len(new_substr) <= max_length:
                new_substr_list.append(new_substr)
        set_substrings.update(new_substr_list)
    return set_substrings

def get_best_substring_for_each(string_list=words, max_length=N):
    all_substrings = {}
    best = {}
    for word in string_list:
        for substring in generate_substrings(word, max_length=max_length):
            if substring not in all_substrings:
                all_substrings[substring] = 0
            all_substrings[substring] = all_substrings[substring] + 1
    for word in string_list:
        best_score = len(string_list) + 1
        best[word] = ''
        for substring in generate_substrings(word=word, max_length=max_length):
            if all_substrings[substring] < best_score:
                best[word] = substring
                best_score = all_substrings[substring]
    return best

print(get_best_substring_for_each(words, N))
```

This program prints the solution:

```
{'barfoo': 'af', 'Foobar': 'Fr', 'Foobaron': 'n', 'footloose': 'os', 'barstool': 'al', 'Foot': 'Ft'}
```

This can still be improved easily by a constant factor, for instance by storing the results of `generate_substrings`instead of computing it twice.

The complexity is `O(n*C(N, L+N))`, where n is the number of words and L the maximum length of a word, and `C(n, k)` is the number of combinations with k elements out of n.

I don't think (not sure though) that you can do much better in the worst case, because it seems hard not to enumerate all possible substrings in the worst case (the last one to be evaluated could be the only one with no redundancy...). Maybe in average you can do better...

Comment: If you keep L and N constant (case of usual words, and a limited N because you want to reduce your data size), then this is O(n), you can't do better. For large L and constant N, this is O(n * L^N), which is still OK I guess. For big L and big N this is very very bad: worst case N=L/2, complexity O(n * (2^L) / sqrt(Pi * L/2))

Comment: You can also easily tweek it to get the shortest substring that still minimizes the collisions for each word

Comment: sorry N=L/2 is not the worst case for N, of course it is N=L. Then the max possible number of substrings for one word is 2^L, so the complexity is O(n*2^L)

Comment: You can improve it much in average (but not at all in worst case) by mixing the two loops, and looking for the big substrings only in words for which you don't have a good one yet.

Comment: This is roughly what I came up with; there should be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a modification to the longest common subsequence algorithm.  In this case you are seeking the shortest unique subsequence.  Shown below is part of a dynamic programming solution which is more efficient than a recursive solution.  The modifications to the longest common subsequence algorithm are described in the comments below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < string2.Length; j++)
        if (string1[i-1] != string2[j-1])   // find characters in the strings that are distinct
            SUS[i][j] = SUS[i-1][j-1] + 1;  // SUS: Shortest Unique Substring
        else
            SUS[i][j] = min(SUS[i-1][j], SUS[i][j-1]);  // find minimum size of distinct strings
```

You can then put this code in a function and call this function for each string in your set to find the length of the shortest unique subsequence in the set.

Once you have the length of the shortest unique subsequence, you can backtrack to print the subsequence.

Answer (score -1):

You should use modified Trie structure, insert strings to a trie in a way that :

```
Foo-bar-on
   -t
bar-stool
   -foo
```

The rest is straightforward, just choose correct compressed node[0] char

That [Radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) should help